# pyenv-win shows Error while installing another version of Python

Tags: python, pip, pyenv, windows-11

I have installed Python 3.11 on the C:\ drive.
Now, I'm planning to install multiple versions of Python without uninstalling 3.11.

To achieve this, I've installed pyenv-win. However, when I try to install Python 3.10.0 through pyenv-win, it shows an error.

```
C:\Users\Siddharth>pyenv install 3.10.0
:: [Info] ::  Mirror: https://www.python.org/ftp/python
:: [Installing] ::  3.10.0 ...
:: [Error] :: error installing pip.
:: [Error] :: couldn't install 3.10.0
```

Comment: Try runnning `pyenv --debug install 3.10.0` and check whats the output.

Answer (score -1):

first download and install python 3.10 in the system. Then search for the path where it is installed,

while created venv follow the below command. Then check for the version python --version

Replace Python39 with Python 3.10 as per your directory

C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m venv venv

Comment: I never have Experience with venv. There is tool called **pyenv-win** to manage the python version. It is so easy to manage globally and locally. I'm having issues with it.
@KiranKumar